# Spring JPATemplate DAO. DELETE Items from table

Tags: spring, jpa, dao

News

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NEWS")

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "News.findAll", query = "SELECT n FROM News n"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "News.delete", query = "DELETE FROM News n WHERE n.newsId in(:ids)")
})

@GenericGenerator(name = "test-increment-strategy", strategy = "increment")
public class News implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3330980835510468207L;
    private Integer newsId;
    private String title;
    private String brief;
    private String content;
    private Date created;
    private String dateCreatedString;

    public News() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NEWS_ID")
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "news_seq")
    // @SequenceGenerator(name = "news_seq", sequenceName = "NEWS_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "test-increment-strategy")
    public Integer getNewsId() {
        return newsId;
    }
```

DAO

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void removeNews(List<Integer> listOfIdNewsForDeleting) throws DAOException {
    EntityManager entityManager = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("News.delete");
    query.setParameter("ids", listOfIdNewsForDeleting);
    int deleted = query.executeUpdate();
}
```

It's unsuccessful attempt delete news.

`TransactionManager` doesn't give transaction for new `EntityManager` which i call.

But i can't use query throw `JpaTemplate`. Have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction manager does not start transactions for manually created entity managers. It only handles container/spring-managed entity managers. And without a transaction you can't delete.

The javadocs of [`JpaTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html) advise you to use the JPA-style data access. So use

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

(check the spring docs for what you need to enable it).

If you really want to huse the `JpaTemplate` then use only it, and don't get the underlying factory.